# Find two non overlapping paths in undirected graph

Tags: java, python, algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence

I've been struggling on how to approach a problem for over two weeks now. I am supposed to generate an undirected graph which represents a map of streets, and I am supposed to divide the map into two sets of non overlapping streets and both paths should be roughly the same distance.

**What kind of algorithm should I use to solve it?**

I'm just looking for a general direction here on what kind of algorithm should I use to do that.

**Edit: (Test Case)**

Lets assume that we have a non weighted, undirected Graph with Vertices A,B,C,D,E

```
A --- B 
|   / | \
|  /  |  C
| /   | / 
D --- E
```

Which means an adjacency matrix like this one:

```
  A  B  C  D  E
A -  1  0  1  0
B 1  -  1  1  1
C 0  1  -  0  1
D 1  1  0  -  1
E 0  1  1  1  -
```

Assuming all edges are undirected, we have the following edges:

```
(a,b) (a,d) (b,d) (b,e) (b,c) (e,d) (e,c)
```

What I want is that through AI, I can take that graph and generate two groups of edges of roughly the same size. (In this particular case, since we have 7 edges, we would get a group of 3 edges and another one of 4 edges.

```
Group 1: (a,b) (a,d) (b,d) (e,d)
A --- B 
|   / 
|  /  
| /     
D --- E 

Group 2: (b,e) (b,c) (e,c)
B 
| \
|  C
| / 
E
```

Notice that all edges in each group are connected by at least one node, that is a requirement.

Another valid solution could be, for example:

```
Group 1: (d,a) (a,b) (b,c) (c,e)
A --- B 
|       \
|       C
|       / 
D     E 
Group 2: (d,b) (b,e) (e,d)
      B 
    / |
   /  |
  /   | 
D --- E
```

And so on, as you see there are many valid solutions but I want an algorithm to find one and I will keep the first one found. How would I do that?

I'm sure that theres a formal way to state this problem, and I will very much appreciate if you tell me how should I do that.

Comment: can you provide a test case?

Comment: not sure what do you mean, what kind of test case?

Comment: you said you need to find two non overlapping paths from a graph. so provide a graph and two non overlapping path of that graph.

Comment: btw do the path have any cost or it takes same amount of cost to traverse every path.

Comment: also what would be source and destination of the paths?

Comment: I see, Well I think is difficult for me to explain a test case in text but I will do my best, give me a few minutes to update the question, For the sake of simplicity lets assume that we have a non weighted graph or that all edges have a cost of 1. We can choose any node as source and destination as long as we visit all edges at least once.

Comment: can there be more than one difference in number of edges in two graphs?

Comment: Ideally we would have either the same number of edges on each group or a difference of 1. But I think that, if that constraint result in a graph without a solution I could accept a greater difference.

Comment: try running BFS from a random node, and count the edges, when you get to 0.5 of the edges (give or take 1) take out the rest of the edges, and check if they are connected, using DFS or BFS, if they are not connected move to the next node and start BFS from there, in total worst case will cost O(nv+n^2). I think it can work

Comment: Thank you trigonom, that was my initial instinct as well, but I had my doubts about BFS and DFS being considered an AI technique, I guess they are. However, I think I'm gonna find an Eulerian path or circuit and split the solution in half, that way I end up with two disjointed sub-graphs. I will however have to make sure that an eulerian path exists, or modify the graph to include one! I just had an eureka moment a few mins back, thanks to everyone, everything helped!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121557/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).